# GWT fail to load when I clear browser cache

Tags: gwt, browser, smartgwt

I have deployed my GWT application on a JBoss server, which is located on a virtual machine. If I open Safari/Firefox/Chrome, clear the cache and then navigate to my app: the app fails to load! I just see a blank screen (the title is loaded).

I use SmartGWT and when I just httpfox to examine the traffic, I can see that most resources (images, javascript) is downloaded, but some SmartGWT js files seems to be hanging.

[image: Screenshot from httpfox when loading my GWT app]

In the screenshot, ISC_core.js and ISC_Foundation.js has not been completely downloaded, and they never are. (It is not always these two files, it can also be different ones, and it changes everytime I retry).

Now, if I reload the browser my app loads perfectly and when I look in httpfox, the files that were not completely downloaded before, is now fetched from the browser cache.

If I clear the browser cache and try again: blank page and same issue.

Does anyone have a clue about what is causing this behaviour and where I should look to fix it?

Note: this only happens when I deploy on my remote virtual machine. If I deploy locally in the same JBoss server setup, I have no problem and cannot reproduce the above issue. Also no problems when I debug in Eclipse and use the Jetty server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is an Known [issue](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/issues/detail?id=36) ..Which is posted on Google groups .

As a side note enable gzip on your jboss also..please refer to this [link](http://jira.geomajas.org/browse/GWT-151) to do that

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the  urls in the screenshot, and when I reload the page, my app is loaded correctly. So I dont think it is the issue, but thank you, though :)